# tr:last-child selector does not work

Tags: html, css

I've rather complex cascade around themed components rendered by C#/Razor code within MS MVC framework, but anyway: according info I'm able reveal in browsers (Firefox 39.0, Chrome 44.0.2403.125 m) there is something strange what I'm not able understand:

I have a selector:

```
table.Theme-DataGrid-Table tr.Theme-DataGrid-Row td
```

and **it works as expected**. But if I added **last-child** selector

```
table.Theme-DataGrid-Table tr:last-child.Theme-DataGrid-Row td
```

nor

```
table.Theme-DataGrid-Table tr.Theme-DataGrid-Row:last-child td
```

the show stops and previously selected style **disappears from all td elements** including the last row even if the last row has still the same class - in browsers's bread-crumbs can be seen:

```
tr#unitorder_9.Theme-DataGrid-Row.Theme-DataGrid-ItemCss
```

Pls, does does anybody know what I'm missing?

Thanx, pf

**UPDATE1**
The code above is actually shown in pop-up jQuery dialog and loaded as partial view into base page's DOM. If I copy div container element and all its content from Browser to Fiddler and supply corresponding .css styles, then :last-child selector **works**.

Could be possible that it depends on the fact, that HTML code of poped-up dialog lives within DOM object of complex basal page?

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure? Does the last row of the table have the `Theme-DataGrid-Row` class?

Comment: Currently it seems to be OK - http://jsfiddle.net/q8w167ch/ but we'd need to see it *not* working in a demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hf9zpzy8/ Check this...... Just as Paulie_D said, do you have a demo?

Comment: @LinkinTED: I've supplied this information in the question. Here is a structure of the last row http://jsfiddle.net/33gsoz6z/ (without CSS and the rest of page, because it is realtive huge). If you think it is not possible to suggest some tips what could be wrong, I suggest to postopone this problem once I will have a time to isolate a structure and  prepare SSCCE. This is low priority problem for me today.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the comment from Paulie_D and Guilherme Silva, it seems to work. So the failure is somewhere in the HTML structure. Please put it in a JSFiddle... the size does not matter (size of the table that is :):) ).

Comment: I know that it works in the simplier cases - I use in many cases, but in this specific case does not.

Comment: I digged around little bit and updated my question. I put code loaded on-demand when pop-up dialog is shown and the selector :last-child works.